# HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

Tags: spring-jdbc

exception is org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0] with root cause
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

Comment: Hey @Sriman Java - welcome to SO. I feel this question needs a bit more information to do a proper assessment and answer. `EmptyResultDataAccessException` sounds like you tried to retrieve data for something that was either empty or didn't exist. Can you post your query and confirm that what you are trying to query isn't empy? Thanks!

Comment: thankq boss  i did solve above issue

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to post your fix as an answer to help future users that find this post.